# yii query builder insert \r\n for textfield

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i'm using yii querybuilder to do the MySQL INSERT command.
It works that the string is stored in the text column.
But when i update the textfield in the form,
\r\n is still there which is expected to be invisible.
how to deal with it?
thanks

```
use yii\db\Query;
$query=new Query;
$this->createCommand()->batchInsert('table',['id','text'],[
  [1,'hello!world!\r\n there is $symbol in the sentence'],
]);
```

p.s.

i tried using `"` instead of `'`, but there is `$` in the string, it will recognize it as a variable which does not exist.

Comment: Use 'hello!world!' . "\r\n" . 'there is $symbol in the sentence'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `'` so `\r\n` will be literal that four chars.

To make it special (carriage return and new line) you have to use `"` to wrap your string.

Comment: @CharlesBao in `"` it'll be treated like variable so you have to escape it with backslash.